# Retrofit with Vaadin UI

Tags: java, api, retrofit, retrofit2, vaadin

I am developing a project with Vaadin where he has to make API calls to some services I have created. To make API calls use retrofit. The problem I'm having is that once I get the (asynchronous) response in the onResponse function override I can't change the UI anymore, otherwise I get the error: "Cannot access state in VaadinSession or UI without locking the session."

Answer (score 3):

You have to update the UI in the access() method:

For example:

```
getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.access(() -> { 
   // update the components
}
```

Please also read the documentation:
https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access

Comment: Did you also take push into use (as explained in Simon's link), or make sure that it's working correctly? If you don't have a working push or polling, no updates will make it to the client-side before the next user interaction.